# Hibernate updating with list

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to update a ManyToMany relation in my update statement.
I'm using Reference class, here is the class :

```
public class Reference implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="user_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_gen", sequenceName="SEQ_USER")
@Column(name = "DOCUMENTID", nullable = false)
private int documentID;

@Column(name = "REFERENCE")
private String reference = "";

@Column(name = "CODE")
private String code = "";

@Column(name = "REMARK")
private String remark = "";

@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title = "";

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "DOCUMENTS_MACHINES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENTID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "MACHINEID") })
private Set<Machine> machines = new HashSet<Machine>();
```

I would like to know if it is possible to update a ManyToMany relations in a HQL statement because session.update(object) would cause conflicts problem because of missing properties.

What I've tried :

```
     String hqlUpdate = "update Reference r " + 
            "set r.title = :title, " +
            "r.machines = :machines " +
            "where r.documentID = :id";

    int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
            .setString("title", reference.getTitle())
            .setParameterList("machines", reference.getMachines())
            .setInteger("id", reference.getDocumentID())
            .executeUpdate();
```

However, it doesn't work, so my question is : Is it possible to update a collection and how ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check that many to many hibernate update mapping query example:

[many to many hibernate update](http://www.easywayserver.com/java/hibernate-many-to-many-mapping-update-query-example/)

Also have a look at CascadeType. You can set the behaviour for save/update operations directly by using the **CascadeType** in the relationship annotation.